# Powershell get content between quotation marks

Tags: powershell

I am getting an output like this

```
Fila 28:
  Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\X000000"

Fila 29:
  Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\E000000"

Fila 30:
  Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\X111111"
```

And I need to filter out everything but the content inside the quotation marks please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, possibly more intuitive, solution using regex with -match and -replace

```
$text = 'Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\X111111"'

$regex = '\s*Nombre del solicitante: "([^"]+)"\s*'
@($text) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1'
```

As a one-liner:

```
@(<command>) -match ''Nombre del solicitante:' -replace '.*"(.+)".*','$1'
```

Wrapping the command output in @() is to make sure you get back an array, even if the command only returns one line, so that the -match operator works as a filter instead of a Boolean true/false test.

@JNK - are you testing with an array (that's what the command ouput is going to produce) ?

```
$text = 
(@'
Fila 28:
  Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\X000000"

Fila 29:
  Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\E000000"

Fila 30:
  Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\X111111"
'@).split("`n") 

$regex = '\s*Nombre del solicitante: "([^"]+)"\s*'
@($text) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1'


CONTOSO\X000000
CONTOSO\E000000
CONTOSO\X111111
```

Edit - to get just the account name, without the domain part:

```
$regex = '\s*Nombre del solicitante: ".+?\\([^"]+)"\s*'
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is it won't filter out the other text...It will keep the non-matching lines in place.

Comment: Thank you, please note that is an output for a command. Is there anyway to select the wanted content in just one line using a pipe after my command?

Comment: The -match operation will filter out the non-matching lines first.

Comment: It's easily done as a one-liner, and you don't need the pipe.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @mjolinor It doesn't, unfortunately. I just tested it.  I still like this better than my own answer but it's not filtering non-matching lines.

Comment: No escapes necessary on the quotes. Inside the regex you have to comply with regex parsing rules, not Powershell.

Comment: :( it's not working for some reason, it seems -match is not a valid cmdlet for my certutil command

Comment: I tested that with the posted data (just updated the answer with the test code so you can verify).

Comment: Thank you! finally did it this way: '$text=certutil.... $regex = '\s*Nombre del solicitante: "([^"]+)"\s*'
@($text) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1'`

Comment: Sorry again @mjolinor I just realized that I need the Samid instead of the UPN, so, what would be the regex if I only need the content between the quotation marks and **after** the backslash: CONTOSO\ **X0000** (Note there is not allways CONTOSO but also other domain names)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily with regex:

```
$s = 'Nombre del solicitante: "CONTOSO\X111111"'

IF ($s -match '(?<=").*(?=")')
    {$matches}
```

`$Matches` will give you an array of every match in the string you examine.  You can iterate through it like any other hashtable to get the values out.